# Why the Output is as it is in this Java Code?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

The following code:

```
public class StrangeClass {
    public static int[] alpha(int[] a) {
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            b[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i];
        return b;
    }

    public static void omega(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length/2; i++) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i];
            a[a.length - 1 - i] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
        System.out.println(matrix.length);
        alpha(matrix[0]);
        omega(matrix[1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Produces the output:

```
2
123
654
```

And I want to know how the Output was reached. The Output here is correct, I just don't understand the concept of how it got to the three lines as the answer.

Comment: Debug it to understand better rather than searching for elaborations.

Comment: do you want 123 as 321 in output?

Comment: And *please* format your code before you post it. And explain what you expected to see and why...

Comment: @user3747720 no aha the output is correct as it is, I just don't understand the concept of how those output are why they are

Answer (score 0):

The `alpha` method returns an array that is sorted in reverse way, while the `omega` method directly reverses the array passed in parameter.
Hence `alpha(matrix[0]);` does nothing you can see while `omega(matrix[1]);` changes the order of the second row of your matrix.
As [Shree Krishna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5067493/shree-krishna) said, you can find it by debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class StrangeClass {
        public static int[] alpha(int[] a) {
            int[] b = new int[a.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                b[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i];
            return b;
        }

        public static void omega(int[] a) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++) {
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i];
                a[a.length - 1 - i] = temp;
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[][] matrix = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
            System.out.println(matrix.length); //Line a
            alpha(matrix[0]); //Line b
            omega(matrix[1]); //Line c
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { //Line d
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Line a prints the length of matrix i.e. two array elements `{ 1, 2, 3 }` and `{ 4, 5, 6 }`

Line b passes the `{ 1, 2, 3 }` by reference but the changes inside alpha are made to another array `b`. So array `{ 1, 2, 3 }` remains intact.

Line c passes `{ 4, 5, 6 }` by reference and the changes are made to same array. As it is passed by reference(by default in java) the value gets reversed(alpha and omega are reversing value of array)

Line d is responsible for printing the matrix array in which `{ 1, 2, 3 }` remains intact which is passed to alpha and `{ 4, 5, 6 }` changes which is passed to omega.

Answer (score 0):

1) `matrix` is an array of 2 arrays, each has 3 int values

2) the method `alpha` returns a new array of int value, with the value in the reversed order as the input array

3) the method `omega` reverses the values of the input array

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays are passed as reference.**

omega reverses the array because the operations take place on array a[] itself (the array that was passed as parameter), while the method alpha created a reversed array in b[] (not the passed array) and returned it.